# How do I get rid of vehicle voltage spikes maybe a choke and capacitor filter?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, dc, inductor

**My Question is:**

Is this a effecient way of filtering high voltage spikes?

If so is the way I drawn the circuit even correct...

How to size the components to work so that any vehicle high voltage spikes get filtered.

**Context**

I have a pump controller circuit that will be powered by a 12v battery that is charged with a stator.

I need to protect from voltage spikes...

For more info look here: 
[Circuit Board Design...Getting Rid Of A Relay and Adding a Choke and Capacitor Filter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429198/circuit-board-design-getting-rid-of-a-relay-and-adding-a-choke-and-capacitor-f)

@Transistor mentioned possibly a choke and capacitor filter...

I've been reading up on this and the more I read the more confused I get.

Here is what I've come up with so far...

I don't know how to size the componets correctly and running a simulation didn't help me...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJWwa9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Figure 1. Clumsy Voltage Filter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3farr.png)</sup>

Figure 2. Pump Controller Circuit

Comment: Did you mean protect the automotive electronics?  from spikes generated by pump switch from **conducted** noise or more likely it is **radiated noise**.  If so which device is affected?  The pump does not need protection from spikes, as it is the generator.

Comment: No there are spikes generated from other solenoids valves on the vehicle before the pump circuit...

Comment: I have not tested this new circuit out as I am using a latching relay with diodes ect. Do I even need to put in a filter? @Sunnyskyguy EE75

Comment: What is I1, it is unclear what you are trying to do, it also depends on what "circuit board" is.

Comment: l1 is supposed to be an Inductive choke... Updated my question

Comment: Google "load dump" or "automotive load dump".  There is an extensive literature on protecting semiconductor devices in automotive environments; somewhat less so, but still extensive, for trucks and heavy equipment.  One or two answers on StackExchange is *not* going to do the topic justice.

Comment: It is also not clear if your problem "egress or ingress", "radiated or conducted" but load dump is the accepted automotive ingress susceptibility test. Also you have no specs regarding any currents, Joules , DCR, Inductance or dI/dt . These MUST be specified to design any snubber circuit or solenoid optimal driver.  The reason is to reduce Q of the impedance ratio of the Snubber and minimize temp. rise from power dissipation

Answer (score 2):

some thing like this, using the popular implementation of a filter ---- one series element and one shunt element

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxBtEw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We add the resistor to dampen. R == sqrt(  L / C).

Comment: What is the heavy wire input/output do? @analogsystemsrf

Comment: build this filter over a square inch of Ground plane. And have both input wires on the left side; put both output wires on the right; notice the 3 groungs?  Keep them far apart.

Comment: As Someone who is not familiar to what you are talking about where would I go to read about what your talking about? @analogsystemsrf

Comment: this is a voltage divider: Vout = Vin * Zshunt / (Zshunt + Zseries). The use of a low-inductance capacitor (surface mount) and those small pieces of foil, has the purpose of making the **SHUNT** become as small as possible, thus the attenuation of high-frequency fast-rise-time trash will the best possible.

Comment: scroll down to the end of this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295629/why-are-many-ir-receivers-in-metal-cages/295689#295689 and notice how GRIDS can be modeled in SPICE. Draw that 1cm by 6cm foil with about 5 by 30 squares; you will see very little interference gets to the RIGHT side; my hand computations show 12dB attenuation per square of distance.